# pyspark with hive - can't properly create with partition and save a table from a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert json files to parquet with very few transformations (adding date) but I then need to partition this data before saving it to parquet.

I'm hitting a wall on this area.

Here is the creation process of the table:

```
    df_temp = spark.read.json(data_location) \
        .filter(
            cond3
        )
    df_temp = df_temp.withColumn("date", fn.to_date(fn.lit(today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))))
    df_temp.createOrReplaceTempView("{}_tmp".format("duration_small"))

    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {1} LIKE {0}_tmp LOCATION '{2}/{1}'".format("duration_small","duration", warehouse_location))
    spark.sql("DESC {}".format("duration"))
```

then regarding the save of the conversion:

```
    df_final.write.mode("append").format("parquet").partitionBy("customer_id", "date").saveAsTable('duration')
```

but this generates the following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: '\nSpecified partitioning does not match that of the existing table default.duration.\nSpecified partition columns: [customer_id, date]\nExisting partition columns: []\n          ;'

the schema being:

```
    root
     |-- action_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- customer_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- duration: long (nullable = true)
     |-- initial_value: string (nullable = true)
     |-- item_class: string (nullable = true)
     |-- set_value: string (nullable = true)
     |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
     |-- stop_time: string (nullable = true)
     |-- undo_event: string (nullable = true)
     |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- day: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- date: date (nullable = true)
```

Thus I tried to change the create table to:

```
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {1} LIKE {0}_tmp PARTITIONED BY (customer_id, date) LOCATION '{2}/{1}'".format("duration_small","duration", warehouse_location))
```

But this create an error like:

> ...mismatched input 'PARTITIONED' expecting ...

So I discovered that PARTITIONED BY doesn't work with `LIKE` but I'm running out of ideas.
if using `USING` instead of `LIKE` I got the error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'It is not allowed to specify partition columns when the table schema is not defined. When the table schema is not provided, schema and partition columns will be inferred.;'

How am I supposed to add a partition when creating the table?

*Ps - Once the schema of the table is defined with the partitions, I want to simply use:*

```
    df_final.write.format("parquet").insertInto('duration')
```

Comment: is duration table already defined? then it doesn't have a partition but you try to append the data with partition.

Comment: well, it's being defined on the CREATE TABLE and I'm trying to figure out how to create it with partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it with spark.

```
    df_temp.read.json...

    df_temp.createOrReplaceTempView("{}_tmp".format("duration_small"))

    spark.sql("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {1}
    USING PARQUET
    PARTITIONED BY (customer_id, date)
    LOCATION '{2}/{1}' AS SELECT * FROM {0}_tmp
    """.format("duration_small","duration", warehouse_location))

    spark.sql("DESC {}".format("duration"))

    df_temp.write.mode("append").partitionBy("customer_id", "date").saveAsTable('duration')
```

I don't know why, but if I can't use insertInto, it uses a weird customer_id out of nowhere and doesn't append the different dates.